# FFMPEG - Moving text to appear every 'X' Seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

This is a ffmpeg command for moving text (left to right)

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/fonts/FreeSans.ttf:text='Hello World':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=16:y=h-line_h-100:x=(2*n)-tw" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy output.mp4`

And I would like to know how to make the moving text to start after 'X' seconds and appear every 'X' seconds ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's right there in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-37). For example to make it appear every 3 seconds for a duration of 1 second you can add the following to your `drawtext` filter:

`enable=lt(mod(t\,3)\,1)`

**Update**: based on the comments it has to be a continuously scrolling text. Here's an example for a text that scrolls the whole width of the video in 10s, after an initial time of 10s and then dissappears for another 10s, in a loop:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf:text='Hello World':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=16:y=h-line_h-100:x=w/10*mod(t\,10):enable=gt(mod(t\,20)\,10)" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy -y output.mp4
```

Details:

- Horizontal movement:
  `x=w/10*mod(t\,10)` where `w` is the input width, `t` is the time, `w/10` is the speed of movement (whole width in 10s) and `t mod 10` is used to repeat every 10s
- Enabling: `enable=gt(mod(t\,20)\,10)`, every 20s show the text animation for 10s after the initial 10s

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it won't work for scrolling text effect. I have tried adding that piece of code before actually. I think we probably still need to make some changes to "x=(2*n)-tw"

Comment: No error when encoding. But the scrolling text doesn't repeat every 'X' seconds. Only scroll for one time. `ffmpeg -i /test/test.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/simhei.ttf:text='Hello World Hello World':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=16:y=h-line_h-100:x=(5*n)-tw:enable=lt(mod(t\,10)\,5)" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy /test/output.mp4`

Comment: I am encountering one small issue. I added (-640) to make the scrolling text move from right to left and start completely off stage (video width is 640px). But when I add the 10 secs delay `enable=gt(t\,10)` , the scroll will not start completely off stage. It will appear and start at some random 'x' position. I believe this happen cus the text have already started moving but it is 'invisible' due to the 10 secs delay. How do i resolve this ?

`y=h-line_h-300:x=w-640/25*mod(t\,100):enable=gt(t\,10)`

Comment: `w - 640/25` order of operations maybe (hint: parentheses) :) ? I gave you the solution, you have to find the logic to tweak it. Good luck.

Comment: @aergistal struggling to figure out how to reverse the scrolling from right to left for a video with width of 1280, unable to figure the logic out, have you got a working example?

Comment: @paj `x=` controls the x position. For right to left you can use `x=w-tw-w/10*mod(t\,10)` where `w` is the frame width, `tw` is the text width and the rest of the expression is the step.

Comment: Is it possible to create a text animation with this effect? I.e. have each character appear after one another?

Comment: @raven I have the feeling the solution would be convoluted. It's probably best to create the animation separately and just overlay it. Or write a filter that enables advanced text animation.