# Is there any way to add drawtext filter in video at the last 3 seconds by enable function in ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I wanna ask that I want to add drawtext filter to the video in last 3 seconds only, may the video of any length like 2 minutes or 20 minutes, whatever. I want it in Python format.

Comment: did you try modules like [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) or [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy)?

Comment: based on [FFMPEG - Moving text to appear every 'X' Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737643/ffmpeg-moving-text-to-appear-every-x-seconds) you can use `enable=` to control when to add filter. Using `enable=gt(t\,3)` (`t > 3`) - you can add text after 3 seconds. If you would know full time then you could use `full_time-t < 3` - I'm not sure if uppercase `T` means full time but it could be `enable=lt(T-t,3)`

Answer (score 2):

With [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy) you can get `duration` or `end` and use it to `start` text at `end-3` or `duration-3`

```
from moviepy.editor import *

video = VideoFileClip("input.mp4")

print('duration:', video.duration)

text = TextClip('Hello', fontsize=70, color='white')
text = text.set_position('center')
text = text.set_start(video.end-3)
text = text.set_end(video.end)
#text = text.set_start(video.duration-3)
#text = text.set_end(video.duration)

result = CompositeVideoClip([video, text])
result.write_videofile("output.mp4")
```

**EDIT:**

The same method with [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

First I get duration and later I use it with `enable=f"between(t,{duration-3},{duration})"`

I use `x='(w-text_w)/2', y='(h-text_h)/2'` to center text.

```
import ffmpeg

info = ffmpeg.probe('input.mp4')
duration = float(info['format']['duration'])

print('duration:', duration)

(
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mp4')
    .drawtext(text='Hello', x='(w-text_w)/2', y='(h-text_h)/2', fontsize=70, fontcolor='red', enable=f'between(t,{duration-3},{duration})')
    .output('output.mp4')
    .run(overwrite_output=True)
)
```

---

**EDIT:**

With `ffmpeg-python` you can even display arguments for program `ffmpeg`

```
video = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(filename)
    .drawtext(text='Hello', x='(w-text_w)/2', y='(h-text_h)/2', fontsize=70, fontcolor='red', enable=f'between(t,{duration-3},{duration})')
    .output('output.mp4')
)

video.run(overwrite_output=True)
    
video.view(detail=True)  # image

print(video.get_args())  # text
```

Result:

```
['-i', 'input.mp4', '-filter_complex', '[0]drawtext=enable=between(t\\,4.036\\,7.036):fontcolor=red:fontsize=70:text=Hello:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2[s0]', '-map', '[s0]', 'output.mp4']
```

[image]